# Does NFKD decompose characters by compatibility and also canonical equivalence?

Tags: javascript, unicode, normalize

After many attempts of understanding I gotta say that I don't get how `String.prototype.normalize()` works. There are a few values that this method can take as parameters: `NFC`, `NFD`, `NFKC`, `NFKD`.

Firstly, I don't get what's the difference between `NFD` and `NFKD`. The spec is very vague about that, so... In some [resource](https://dencode.com/en/string/unicode-normalization) I've read that `NFD` decomposes characters by canonical equivalence. For example:

```
"â" (U+00E2) -> "a" (U+0061) + " ̂" (U+0302)
```

And `NFKD` decomposes characters by compatibility. For example:

```
"ﬁ" (U+FB01) -> "f" (U+0066) + "i" (U+0069)
```

But that's not exactly true. `NFKD` not only decomposes characters by compatibility. Also it perfectly can deal with the first example:

```js
let s = `\u00E2`; //"â" 
console.log(s.normalize('NFD').length); //2
console.log(s.normalize('NFKD').length); //2
```

Does it mean that `NFKD` can decompose characters by compatibility and also canonical equivalence? And `NFD` decomposes characters only by canonical equivalence...?

```js
let s = `\uFB01`; //"ﬁ"
console.log(s.normalize('NFD').length); //1
```

Comment: [This might be of interest, if you haven't seen it already.](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)

Comment: The subject appears to be much more complicated than I formerly imagined. That's a complicated paper, but it refers to extensive amounts of other writing about how Unicode is supposed to work.

Comment: [Normalization Forms](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Normalization_Forms_Table)

Comment: Both canonical and compatibility equivalences are explained in more detail in [Chapter 2, General Structure](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/ch02.pdf), and [Chapter 3, Conformance](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/ch03.pdf), in [Unicode](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unicode](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Description_Norm)

> The type of full decomposition chosen depends on which Unicode
> Normalization Form is involved. For NFC or NFD, one does a full
> canonical decomposition, which makes use of only canonical
> Decomposition_Mapping values. ***For NFKC or NFKD, one does a full
> compatibility decomposition, which makes use of canonical and
> compatibility Decomposition_Mapping values.***

That's why NFC/NFD and NFKC/NFKD work like that:

```js
let s1 = '\uFB00'; //"ﬀ"
let s2 = '\u0066\u0066'; //"ff"
console.log(s1.normalize('NFD').length); //doesn't work with compatible -- only can. eq.

let t1 = `\u00F4`; //ô
let t2 = `\u006F\u0302`; //ô
console.log(t1.normalize('NFKD').length); //also works with can. eq.
console.log(t2.normalize('NFKC').length); //also works with can. eq.
```

And that's complitly understandable because...

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize#compatibility_normalization)

> All canonically equivalent sequences are also compatible, but not vice versa.